# Specific values as argument for function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a function which has 1 parameter/argument of type String:

```
        public void foo(String myParam)
        {
           //do something
        }
```

the possible values of the string are restricted (eg.  "test","test2" and "test3"), any different value of myParam would cause an error.

Is it possible to restrict the possible values of myParam without a switch case which would check the value of myParam?

It would also be possible to pass a different object to my function which wraps the real value I need.

Is there a standard/best way solution for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could create an enum

```
public enum MyParam
{
    test,
    test2,
    test3
}
```

And use `ToString` to get the string representation of your `enum`

```
public void foo(MyParam myParam)
{
    if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyParam),myParam))
        throw new ArgumentException();
    myParamString = myParam.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Yep, this seems exactly suited for an enum. You can validate it by doing `Contract.Requires(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyParam), value))`

Comment: how would look a call of that function?

Comment: You could call it like `foo(MyParam.test)` or assign an `enum` value to a variable and pass it in.

Comment: Note that you still need to validate the input. Someone could call it with: `foo((MyParam)-1214324)`, for example.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I've added the validation.  Not something I've considered when using enums before.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to restrict such values is to check against them.

You could use direct string comparisons or regular expression matches - if the string fails the matches throw an `InvalidArgumentException`.

Another option is to create a class wrapping the string - on construction of the class (passing in the wrapped string as a constructor argument), you would test as above.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Regular Expressions`; .NET provides the Namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions` where there is a `Regex`-class:

```
public void foo(String myParam){

Regex regex = new Regex(@"test\d");
if(regex.IsMatch(myParam))
   //myParam matches regex
}
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx) where there is also information on RegEx.

Comment: test1, test2 ,test3 was just an example, it could also be "tdfsg","dcudf" and "cvb"  but thanks for your help :)